# Преобразить цикл в рекурсию С++

Tags: c++, циклы, рекурсия

Всем доброго времени суток. Я студентка 1 курса, преподаватель по программированию дал интересное задание: создать калькулятор комплексных чисел(именно их сумму), используя рекурсивный алгоритм Карацубы. Смогла справиться с этой задачей лишь с помощью циклов, пока что слабо представляю, где здесь можно использовать рекурсию. Буду благодарна за любую помощь. Код калькулятора ниже:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// подсчет количества разрядов
int getLength(long long value) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        counter++;
        value /= 10;
    }
    return counter;
}

long long multiply(long long x, long long y) {
    int xLength = getLength(x);
    int yLength = getLength(y);

    // наибольший из двоих значений
    int N = (int)(fmax(xLength, yLength));

    // если максимальная длина достаточно маленькая, быстрее просто перемножить два числа обычным методом
    if (N < 10)
        return x * y;

    
    N = (N / 2) + (N % 2);
    // смещение для десятичной системы счисления
    long long multiplier = pow(10, N);

    long long b = x / multiplier;
    long long a = x - (b * multiplier);
    long long d = y / multiplier;
    long long c = y - (d * multiplier);

    long long d0 = multiply(a, c);
    long long d1 = multiply(a + b, c + d);
    long long d2 = multiply(b, d);

    // формула с(t)
    return d0 + ((d1 - d0 - d2) * multiplier) + (d2 * (long long)(pow(10, 2 * N)));

}
int main()
{
    
    long long a, b, c, d;
    cout << "a: "; cin >> a;
    cout << "b: "; cin >> b;
    cout << "c: "; cin >> c;
    cout << "d: "; cin >> d;
    cout << "r = " << (a * c - b * d) << endl;
    cout << "s = " << (a * d + b * c) << "i" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вы ведь ее уже используете, когда вычисляете d0, d1 и d2 в multiply

Comment: но мне надо цикл while заменить на рекурсию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз надо заменить на рекурсию `while` -

```
int getLengthRec(long long value) {
    if (value == 0) return 0;
    return getLengthRec(value/10) + 1;
    }
```